# How to add required headers to securitySchemas in OpenAPI

Tags: swagger, openapi, openapi-generator, swagger-codegen

I'm trying to generate OpenAPI schema (swagger file) for my API which requires a mandatory header for getting a token (header x-mandatory-header). How should I add this information to the schema so users of my API know about it and can generate client code including this mandatory header?

Part of my OpenAPI schema:

```html
securitySchemes:
    jwt:
      type: oauth2
      flows:
        clientCredentials:
          tokenUrl: 'https://my-host/sst/v1/oauth2/token'
          scopes: {}
```

I didn't find anything helpful in open API documentation https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/. I also tried to backward engineer generated Java clients to find clues about this possibility without luck.